# How to set curl request properly in php laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am trying to make a curl request!
Here I can make this request using postman and I am getting response perfectly using postman:

My Body parameter is: sub_domain
and my header is `x-api-key` value is something `ZYWHUYAOSYSOASYYY`

Ind i can get response perfectly!
But here want to make curl request on my end:

My Controller Code:

```
     public function curlPost()
      {
    $data1 = [
        'sub_domain' => 'value_1',
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://uwxcdwsc0k.execute-api.us-east- 
        1.amazonaws.com/prod/domain",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data1),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            // Set here required headers
            "x-api-key: KiZTkTO9Ex2ZCOr7xmYRA4bInlJc9kVNrVN2INrc",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        print_r(json_decode($response));
    }
}
```

and my Routes/api.php:

```
 Route::post('subdomain', 'ApiController@curlPost');
```

and when i hit post request using postman i get error

```
       stdClass Object
          (
         [code] => [422] Unprocessable Entity
          [message] => sub_domain is required
           )
```

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please use some library which will help you in long run like Guzzle http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your header array,

```
'Content-Type:application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the $data an array as below:

```
   $data1 = array(
     'sub_domain' => 'value_1'

    );
```

Cheers